# Minesweeper JavaFX app

Tags: java, javafx, minesweeper

This is my Minesweeper JavaFx app. It is working without any weird bugs, at least none that I found. I am not too concerned about the way it looks either, the main reason I post this here is to get an opinion on the design and code. I have gone for a more functional approach but it kinda feels weird, a mid point between functional and object oriented without doing anything right. I would love some input on how to make it more functional. Also please point out any bad habits or patterns.

```
package minesweeper;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application{
    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
        AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/minesweeper/minesweeper.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Minesweeper");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

```
package minesweeper;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

public class ControllerMenu {
    @FXML public AnchorPane root;
    @FXML public Button ButtonPlay, ButtonHelp, ButtonExit;

    public void play() throws IOException{
        root.getScene().setRoot(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/minesweeper/Game.fxml")));
    }

    public void exit(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

---

```
package minesweeper;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

class Tile extends Button {
    private boolean flagged, mine;
    private final int x, y;
    private int value;

    Tile(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        this.setPrefSize(28, 28);
    }

    int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(int n){
        value = n;
    }

    void flag(){
        flagged = !flagged;
    }

    boolean isFlagged(){
        return flagged;
    }

    void setMine(){
        mine = true;
        value = 9;
    }

    boolean isMine(){
        return mine;
    }

    void disable(){
        this.setDisable(true);

        if(mine)
            this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        else if (value > 0)
            this.setText(value+"");
    }
}
```

---

```
package minesweeper;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Board {
    final int ROWS = 25;
    final int COLUMNS = 25;
    final int MINES = 75;
    private final Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[ROWS][COLUMNS];

    Board() {
        makeTiles();
        addMines();
        updateValues();
    }

    Tile getTile(int x, int y) {
        return tiles[x][y];
    }

    private LinkedList<Tile> flatTiles() {
        LinkedList<Tile> flatTiles = new LinkedList<>();
        Arrays.stream(tiles).forEach(t -> flatTiles.addAll(Arrays.asList(t)));
        return flatTiles;
    }

    private void makeTiles() {
        IntStream.range(0, ROWS)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(r -> IntStream.range(0, COLUMNS)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(c -> tiles[r][c] = new Tile(r, c)));
    }

    private void addMines() {
        Random rng = new Random();
        Set<List<Integer>> MineCoordinates = new HashSet<>(MINES);

        while (MineCoordinates.size() < MINES)
            MineCoordinates.add(List.of(rng.nextInt(ROWS), rng.nextInt(COLUMNS)));

        for(List<Integer> x : MineCoordinates)
            tiles[ x.get(0) ][ x.get(1) ].setMine();
    }

    private void updateValues() {
        flatTiles().stream().filter(t -> !t.isMine())
            .forEach(t -> t.setValue((int) adjacent(t).stream()
                .parallel()
                .filter(Tile::isMine)
                .count()));
    }

    List<Tile> adjacent(Tile tile) {
        List<Tile> adjacent = new LinkedList<>();
        int neighbors[] = {-1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};

        for(int i=0; i<neighbors.length; i+=2){
            int Newx = tile.getX()+neighbors[i];
            int Newy = tile.getY()+neighbors[i+1];

            if (Newx>=0 && Newx<25 && Newy>=0 && Newy<25)
                adjacent.add(tiles[Newx][Newy]);
        }
        return adjacent;
    }
}
```

---

```
package minesweeper;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Game {
    @FXML public AnchorPane gameScene;
    @FXML public Pane Container;
    @FXML public Label mines, tiles;
    private final Board board = new Board();
    private int mineCount = 0, tileCount = 0;

    public void initialize(){
        setUpGrid();
        gameScene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (KeyCode.ESCAPE == e.getCode())
                try {
                    AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/minesweeper/minesweeper.fxml"));
                    gameScene.getScene().setRoot(root);
                }catch (IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        });
        mines.setText("Mines: 0/" + board.MINES);
        tiles.setText("Tiles: 0/" + board.ROWS * board.COLUMNS);
    }

    private void reveal(Tile tile) {
        tile.disable();
        tileCounter();

        if (tile.isMine())
            gameover(false);
        else if (tile.getValue() == 0)
            board.adjacent(tile).stream()
                .filter(e -> !(e.isDisabled() || e.isMine()))
                .forEach(this::reveal);
    }

    private void flag(Tile t){
        mineCounter(!t.isFlagged());
        t.flag();
        t.setText(t.isFlagged() ? "O" : "");
    }

    private void gameover(boolean won){
        try{
            AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/minesweeper/" + (won ? "Victory" : "Loss") + ".fxml"));
            Timeline tl = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> gameScene.getScene().setRoot(root)));
            tl.play();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void mineCounter(boolean inc){
        mines.setText("Mines: " + (inc ? ++mineCount : --mineCount) + "/" +board.MINES);
    }

    private void tileCounter(){
        tiles.setText("Tiles: "+ ++tileCount + "/" +board.ROWS*board.COLUMNS);
        if(gameWon())
            gameover(true);
    }

    private boolean gameWon(){
        return tileCount == board.ROWS * board.COLUMNS - board.MINES;
    }

    private void setUpGrid(){
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        grid.setHgap(1);
        grid.setVgap(1);

        IntStream.range(0, board.ROWS)
            .forEach(r -> IntStream.range(0, board.COLUMNS)
                .forEach(c -> grid.add(createTile(r, c), c, r)));

        Container.getChildren().add(grid);
    }

    private Tile createTile(int x, int y){
        final Tile tile = board.getTile(x, y);
        tile.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if(e.getButton()==MouseButton.PRIMARY)
                reveal(tile);
            else
                flag(tile);
        });
        return tile;
    }
}
```

---

```
package minesweeper;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class ReplayController {
    @FXML Button replay;

    public void PlayAgain() throws Exception{
        replay.getScene().setRoot(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Game.fxml")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code.

## General coding

You declare member variables of the same type in one line. This is an unusual way to do it. It is certainly not a problem as long as you are the only one working on your code. But when You join a team it is important to negotiate that with the others...

## Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming. So always take your time to think carefully of your identifier names.

#### Naming Conventions

It looks like you already know the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) but you don't strictly follow them.

- Variables should begin with a lowercase letter but you have quite a lot starting with upper case.
- methods should start with a *verb* that points to what will be done in the method. E.g. your method `Board.adjacent(Tile tile)` should better be named `Board.findAdjacentOf(Tile tile)`.
- Variables holding a `boolean` or methods returning a `boolean` should start with *is*, *has*, *can* or alike.

## Functional Programming

#### FP is about immutable, independend data

Any book about *functional programming* states that it is all about *flow of stateless independend data*. The main idea of FP is that you have *immutable data* having no relationship to each other which you process to create other *immutable data*. That means in turn that you cannot transcript anything to a *functional program* that depends on state or where the data have some sort of *dependency* to each other.

However, one of that books on FP (teaching *closure*) stated that you create "pearls of FP code* to be integrated in your "ordinary" program.

The problem I have with your code in this respect is that the `Tile` objects your functional code works on are *mutable*, that means they have *state* that changes during the programs runtime. 
E.g. your methods `updateValues()` and `makeTiles()` violate the FP principle of working on and with immutable data.
As a rule of thumb: if you cannot replace `.forEach()` the behavior you want to implement might not be suitable to be solved with a FP approach.

For your program that means that you have parts that *look like* FP (because you use Java8s "functional API") but they are not.

#### be consequent with you coding style.

On the other hand you have some places in your code where you miss to use a FP approach.
E.g. the `adjacent` method could be implemented in an FP way like this:

```
 private static final int X = 0,Y = 1; // avoid "magic numbers"
 private static final int[][] neighborOffsets // does not change during program runtime
    = {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}; // show that these are "pairs", not individual independend values

 private boolean isInGrid(int neighborIndex){ // helper method
    return 0<=neighborIndex && 25> neighborIndex);
 }

 List<Tile> adjacent(Tile tile) {
   return  Straem.of(neighborOffsets)
                 .filter(offset-> isInGrid(tile.getX()+offset[X]) && isInGrid(tile.getY()+offset[Y]))
                 .map(offset-> tiles[tile.getX()+offset[X]][tile.getY()+offset[Y]])
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

The difference to your "flawed" functional approaches in `updateValues()` and `makeTiles()` is that here a *new collection* is created and the state of the existing data is not changed.

## Conclusion

*Functional Programming* is just another tool in the programmers tool box, but its a very special that is useful only in certain situations. Nails are not useless just because you found a screwdriver next to your hammer...

Comment: That is actually way more useful than I could have hoped for. I will take to heart each of your points (since all make sense to me) and will rewrite some stuff. Thank you for your time and effort to provide examples.